# Keep-visible header rows/columns become transparent

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I had a search for this but couldn't find anything.  I set the Tablix "Row headers - keep header visible while scrolling" property.  This works fine.  Just a couple of days ago, though the report starts making these header cells transparent, so that you can see the data rows through them.  (Image attached shows same effect but with column headers).

[image: Header row and data row both shown]

As far as I know I didn't change anything in the report.

This happens in Visual Studio, and when the report is deployed to SSRS - both when viewed in Chrome and in IE.

Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Versions:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.61021.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL 2014 Reporting Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the background for a cell is transparent. To prevent overlapping text from showing through the row headers, set the background color for the overlapping rows to a solid color such as White.

Comment: Also, set the BackgroundColor of the Tablix to a color such as White or else you will see data scroll behind the header at the very top.

Comment: I would never have thought of that!  Works perfectly, now that you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help! I struggled with this as well when it dawned on me about the transparency. It took me back to my old Visual Basic days.